# How to set up images and proper contenthash links with webpack4 in node.js application?

Tags: node.js, ejs, webpack-4

Total newbie to both Node.js and Webpack!
Now I am at the last stage before deployment of my small node.js project, and I have problems with images and contenthash links.

So this project has 4 pages, 2 are static html (don't have functional js linked to them but I created two just to import css file!), 2 are ejs files rendered from the server using json files, and they also have their own respective functional js files. All 4 share 1 styles.css.

My goal is to use webpack to minify html, css, using babel to translate all js to older version, then minify it as well. After my set up I realized two problems:
1. the images aren't all included in the public/imgs folder that I plan to put them to. Why? 
Answer: upon some research I think the reason is that I have to import all imgs in my js file. One img is used as background in url() in my css, and I imported the css in the js file, this image is correctly copied to public/imgs and a hash was added to it as well. Correct me if I'm wrong!
2. Even they all get moved there, the links in the json files are then not valid. So in this case, how do I handle all the images so they render beautifully in both static and my ejs files(images will be from json files)? Of course I can copy my whole original image folder here since it's a small project, but I just wonder what do people do in large project when it's this case? 
3. I heard we should use [contenthash] to generate new built files, but again in this case, my ejs files don't recognize the new links (both css and js ) any more. So what should I do with my ejs files for them to embed dynamic files?

Here is my webpack.prod.js

```
const path = require("path")
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    about: './src/about.js',
    store: './src/store.js',
    fans: './src/fans.js'
  },

  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public")
  },

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        minify: {
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true
        },
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['index'],
        filename: 'index.html'
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/about.html",
        minify: {
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true
        },
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['about'],
        filename: 'about.html'
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ 
        filename: "styles.[contenthash].css", 
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"}),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(), 
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
            "css-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: {
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
                outputPath: "imgs"}
                }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'fonts'
                }
            }]
        }  
    ]
    }
}
```